# Menu mudar cor e descrição ao ser selecionado

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Olá, estava tentando criar um menu que ao ser selecionado ele mudar de cor, porém ao selecionar outro a cor dele volta ao normal e o outro ativa a cor.
Também ao ser selecionado, o texto base muda, por exemplo:

vi nesse site e estava tentando utilizar como base:
http://www.barietoner.com.br/servicos.html

Meu code está assim:

```
  <div class='tabs tabs_animate'>
         <center> <ul class='horizontal'> 
            <li><a href="#div1">Ativa Descrição 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#div2">Ativa Descrição 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#div3">Ativa Descrição 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#div4">Ativa Descrição 4</a></li>
          </ul> </center>
         <li> <div id="div1"> ativa quando clicar no 1° butão</div></li>
         <li> <div id="div2"> ativa quando clicar no 2° butão</div></li>
         <li> <div id="div3"> ativa quando clicar no 3° butão</div></li>
         <li> <div id="div4"> ativa quando clicar no 4° butão</div></li>
```

Css:

```
        /**
         * TABS
         *
         *                         
         */
        .tabs > DIV {
            /*border-top: 1px solid #c7c7c7*/
            margin-top: 10px;
            background: white !important;
            /*border-bottom: 4px solid #E95855 !important;*/
        }


        .tabs UL.horizontal {
            list-style: none outside none;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .tabs LI {
            background: white;
            border-bottom: 4px solid #E5E5E5;
            margin: 0 10px 0 0;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .tabs A {
            color: #ccc;
            display: block;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 300;
            padding: 14px 24px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Js:

```
                    !function($,window,undefined){"use strict";$.fn.tabslet=function(options)
        {var defaults={mouseevent:"click",attribute:"href",animation:!1,autorotate:!1,deeplinking:!1,pauseonhover:!0,
        delay:2e3,active:1,container:!1,controls:{prev:".prev",next:".next"}},options=$.extend(defaults,options);
        return this.each(function(){function deep_link(){var t=[];elements.find("a").each(function(){t.push($(this)
        .attr($this.opts.attribute))});var e=$.inArray(location.hash,t);return e>-1?e+1:$this.data("active")||options.active}
        var $this=$(this),_cache_li=[],_cache_div=[],_container=options.container?$(options.container):$this,_tabs=_container.find("> div");_tabs.each
        (function(){_cache_div.push($(this).css("display"))});var elements=$this.find("> ul > li"),i=options.active-1;
        if(!$this.data("tabslet-init")){$this.data("tabslet-init",!0),$this.opts=[],$.map(
        ["mouseevent","attribute","animation","autorotate","deeplinking","pauseonhover","delay","container"],
        function(t){$this.opts[t]=$this.data(t)||options[t]}),$this.opts.active=$this.opts.deeplinking?deep_link()
        :$this.data("active")||options.active,_tabs.hide(),$this.opts.active&&(_tabs.eq($this.opts.active-1).show(),
        elements.eq($this.opts.active-1).addClass("active"));var fn=eval(function(t,e){var o=e?elements.find
        ("a["+$this.opts.attribute+"="+e+"]").parent():$(this);o.trigger("_before"),elements.removeClass("active"),
        o.addClass("active"),_tabs.hide(),i=elements.index(o);var n=e||o.find("a").attr($this.opts.attribute);
        return $this.opts.deeplinking&&(location.hash=n),$this.opts.animation?_container.find(n).animate({opacity:"show"},
        "slow",function(){o.trigger("_after")}):(_container.find(n).show(),o.trigger("_after")),!1}),init=eval("elements.
        "+$this.opts.mouseevent+"(fn)"),t,forward=function(){i=++i%elements.length,"hover"==$this.opts.mouseevent?elements.eq(i)
        .trigger("mouseover"):elements.eq(i).click(),$this.opts.autorotate&&(clearTimeout(t),
        t=setTimeout(forward,$this.opts.delay),$this.mouseover(function(){$this.opts.pauseonhover&&
        clearTimeout(t)}))};$this.opts.autorotate&&(t=setTimeout(forward,$this.opts.delay),$this.hover
        (function(){$this.opts.pauseonhover&&clearTimeout(t)},function(){t=setTimeout(forward,$this.opts.delay)}
        ),$this.opts.pauseonhover&&$this.on("mouseleave",function(){clearTimeout(t),t=setTimeout
        (forward,$this.opts.delay)}));var move=function(t){"forward"==t&&(i=++i%elements.length),"backward"==t&&
        (i=--i%elements.length),elements.eq(i).click()};$this.find(options.controls.next).click(function()
        {move("forward")}),$this.find(options.controls.prev).click(function(){move("backward")}),$this.on
        ("show",function(t,e){fn(t,e)}),$this.on("next",function(){move("forward")}),$this.on("prev",function()
        {move("backward")}),$this.on("destroy",function(){$(this).removeData().find("> ul li").each(function()
        {$(this).removeClass("active")}),_tabs.each(function(t){$(this).removeAttr("style").css("display",_cache_div[t])})})}})},$
        (document).ready(function(){$('[data-toggle="tabslet"]').tabslet()})}(jQuery);
```

Porém ele não funciona... Teria alguma forma de consertar ou criar de forma simples?

Comment: Mano, sério que tu colocou um Javascript minificado aqui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi corretamente sua pergunta mas acredito que você pode fazer isso usando os seletores :hover e :select do CSS

Exemplo:

CSS:

```
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">        
    .menu li { display: inline; background: #999;  }
    .menu li:hover { background: #222; }
    .menu li:select { background: #00f; }
  </style>
```

html:

```
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Notícias</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Assim, na propriedade :hover você define a cor que deve aparecer quando o mouse estiver sobre o link e em :select você deve a cor que aparece quando for selecionado.

Referencias:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Obrigado, basicamente era a função select que estava atrás o resto já consegui resolver, agradeço amigo.